# Creating simple yes or no formula for an audit

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create a formula in excel as part of an audit.

If each column is filled in "yes" I need the end column to turn green, and if there are any nos I need it to turn red.

Keeping in mind some of the columns may be blank

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It would be good if you could post anything you have tried, as it is useful for us to see what you have accomplished so far, and what you specifically need help with. That being said, you might want to look on google for "Conditional Formatting". That should accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: I think you should confirm the use of the word "column" in your question. Consider these as completely different meanings: Cell, Column and Row. Your question produces widely vague images as written. Also post dummy data and desired results.

Comment: Generally you will get a more positive response if you provide evidence you have tried one or two things to solve the problem yourself. Screenshots are always welcome as well. As it stands, your question is not showing a great deal of effort to make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldd3g.png)

In the image attached is this what you are trying to achieved?
Then create two conditional format with formula insert the below formula and the color you wanted to use, in this case you want to be Green and Red.

=ISNONTEXT(B3)=TRUE
=ISNONTEXT(B3)=FALSE